# Redirecting a subdomain to another subdomain in the same hosted zone in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-route53

Let's say I have **B.example.com**. B is dead, meaning when I try to go to that subdomain, I get 404. I want to redirect all requests from B.example.com to **A.example.com**, which is a fully working subdomain. This is all hosted on AWS.

I tried the following:

-created S3 bucket called **B.example.com**, enabled public access

-made it a static website hosting bucket, with Redirect Requests to **A.example.com**m, protocol https

-created a new record under **example.com** domain called **B**

-chose **A type, IPv4**, simple routing policy

-enabled Alias, picked my s3 bucket as the endpoint, and saved it

-tried going to **B.example.com**, it just times out now

I feel like there is an easier way to go about this. This was provided by ChatGPT. Tried it, didn't work. Help welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your DNS, can you just update your `A` subdomain to point to your `B` subdomain and then configure the application on `B` to perform the redirect?

If not you probably need to use CloudFront & S3 static sites(updating your DNS to cloudfrount + setup a certificate in ACM) if your apps are using HTTPS as S3 static sites do not support HTTP. See https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudfront-redirect-domain

Answer (score 0):

*You should use `CNAME` records for that purpose, **which routes traffic to another domain name.***

Hosted zone name that you should edit will be `example.com`

The final Records format should be

Record name / Type / Alias / Value/ Route traffic to

A.example.com / C / No / B.example.com